# Radio button siempre sale el mismo mensaje

Tags: javascript, jquery, radiobutton

¿Por qué siempre sale 'Soy empleado'?¿Como se hace para actuar según el radio button seleccionado?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.EmpCli').change(function() {
    var valor = $('.EmpCli').val;

    if (valor = 'empleado') {
      alert('soy Empleado');
    } else if (valor = 'cliente') {
      alert('soy cliente');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Cliente</label>
<input type="radio" name="EmpCli" class="EmpCli" value="cliente">

<label>Empleado</label>
<input type="radio" name="EmpCli" class="EmpCli" value="empleado">
```

Comment: Te falta un `=` en los if (bueno, dos más si quiere validar el tipo)

Comment: en el if no estas comparado el valor, asi que te falta un = , seguido $('.EmpCli').val, val es un metodo no propiedad asi que es .val(), luego ahi en estas obteniendo los 2 radios, para obtener el valor del radio seleccionado deberias de usar el selector :checked, quedando de esta manera => var valor = $('.EmpCli:checked').val(); 

Agrego tu codigo a un fiddle => https://jsfiddle.net/h5ueo0du/1/

Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes varios errores:

`val` es un método no una propiedad por lo que te faltan los paréntesis para recuperar el valor del elemento

Deberías tomar el valor del elemento marcado (`:checked`)

Las comparaciones de valores en JavaScript no se realizan con un símbolo igual (`=`), si no con dos (`==`) o, mejor, con tres para hacer una comparación estricta (`===`):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.EmpCli').change(function() {
    var valor = $('.EmpCli:checked').val();

    if (valor === 'empleado') {
      alert('soy Empleado');
    } else if (valor === 'cliente') {
      alert('soy cliente');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Cliente</label>
<input type="radio" name="EmpCli" class="EmpCli" value="cliente">

<label>Empleado</label>
<input type="radio" name="EmpCli" class="EmpCli" value="empleado">
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes un problema de sintaxis básico. Recuerda que para las condicionales IF y comparar un valor se debe hacer con doble signo de igual "==", en cuanto a obtener el radio que se cambio si debes cambiar un poco tu código.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.EmpCli').change(function() {
    var valor = $(this).val();  // Se obtiene el 'value' del radio que llama al evento change

    if (valor == 'empleado') {   // Doble signo de igual ==
      alert('soy Empleado');
    } else if (valor == 'cliente') {   // Doble signo de igual ==
      alert('soy cliente');
    }
  });

});
```

Si necesitas revisar que el elemento este "checkeado" o "marcado" puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
  alert("Marcado");
}
```